# android data binding: how to get useful error messages

Tags: android, android-databinding

In android studio 2.1, the compile time error messages from xml mistakes are entirely non-helpful:

```
Error:(11, 41) error: package mypackage.databinding does not exist
Error:(15, 13) error: cannot find symbol class MyActivityBinding
```

The real error would usually be something like "there's no such attribute `android:adapter`", or "variable foo doesn't contain property bar" or something like that. But instead of actually showing such errors, it shows the above unhelpful ones, which only tell you that the bindings weren't generated because of some unknown error.

Answer (score 20):

The way I use in Android Studio 4.0:

1. Select the top level `Build: failed` item on the `Build Output` panel

   [image: Failed build output panel]
2. On the right part click `Run with --stacktrace`. When build is finished select the top `Build: failed` item again on the left panel. You'll get a databinding error description on the right panel:

   [image]
   In my case it's:

   > [databinding] {"msg":"Cannot find a getter for \u003ccom.google.android.material.slider.Slider app:value\u003e that accepts parameter type \u0027java.lang.Float\u0027\n\nIf a binding adapter provides the getter, check that the adapter is annotated correctly and that the parameter type matches.","file":"SliderDatabinding\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml","pos":[{"line0":14,"col0":8,"line1":21,"col1":41}]}

Comment: You saved my day. Was struggling to find the exact issue. This helped to find the issue and solve it in seconds

Answer (score 8):

Clink on Toogle View, under the 'Build' icon will give you details logs

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There's no easy way for now. In general, if you face such compilation error and error messages point at missing databinding classes it is usually either bad reference from layout (i.e. you try to access members classes you assigned do not expose - usually happens when you c&p layouts).

Even worse, when you use other code generating libraries (Icepick, Butterknife, etc) then the real culprit can be often in code completely unrelated to binding. So when something like this occur in my code, I usually check `Gradle Console` view and read it from the end up, ignoring all error messages related to databinding like "missing class" or "package does not exists"

Answer (score 3):

One way of getting the proper error is to run gradle in a terminal with '--info', like:

```
gradle :app:build --info
```

That's not exactly integrated into AS, so I can't really accept that answer.